# ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity() throws ClassCastException for libraries

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, classcastexception

I am writing Android JUnit test cases for Project A which has Project B as a library (Project Properties / Android / Library).  My test cases need to access resources (view ids, strings, etc.) from both Project A and Project B.  If I add Project A and/or Project B as Android / Libraries or as Java Build Path / Projects to my test project, any call to ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity() throws a ClassCastException.

If I don't add them, the call returns the appropriate Activity, but I don't have access to the resource ids of the two projects under test.  I also don't have access to the objects in Project B, which are needed to properly test Project A.  I can't use mock objects here.

Has anybody encountered and resolved this before?

Comment: _I don't have access to the resource ids of the two projects under test_, post source with logcat would help others find your issue.

Comment: I'm working under NDA and can't post source or logcat data (wish I could).  I know it makes answering this question harder...

Answer (score 0):

Try this to access resources from the library: (I think it will work)

```
getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources()...;
```

This will load resources from the test project: (definitely works)

```
getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources()...;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am able to get to the resources using the methods you describe above.  But I need access to the public classes and interfaces of the library project as well.  I've edited the question to indicate this.